# Java web service missing hibernate.dialect

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create web service with creation to oracle database. As a server I use Wildfly  so I initialized JNDI connection using Administrative console in browser.

Standalone.xml

```
    {
...
                    <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/ora" pool-name="ora" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:maindatabase</connection-url>
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                        <driver>ora</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>C##Edgar</user-name>
                            <password>2301910</password>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        </validation>
                        <statement>
                            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                        </statement>
                    </datasource>
...
    }
```

But after creating the JPA project and adding `<jta-data-source>` in `persistance.xml` it throws me an exception when I try to create `.ear` file and deploy project.

Persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Model">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/ora</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exception is:

```
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."App1.ear#Model"
      service jboss.persistenceunit."App1.ear#Model": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."App1.ear#Model": org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dial
ect to use [name=Oracle, majorVersion=12]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I missed or done wrong?

Comment: Can the problem should be that you mean 'persistence.xml' not persistance.xml

Comment: what do you mean? 'persistance.xml' was  made automaticaly by exlipse when created JPA project

Comment: the right name for "persistance.xml" is "persistence.xml". I think he cant find it because wrong name. Can you test it?

Comment: no, it just i made the mistake here :)

Comment: Hope this should help you https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1078270